# String or unicode input unrecognized as WKT EWKT, and HEXEWKB error when POST

Tags: python, django, forms, postgis, geodjango

I have a GeoDjango project that i'm working on right now and I'm currently receiving the String or unicode input unrecognized as WKT EWKT, and HEXEWKB error when submitting a form.
      The form is populated with a set of images that have been generated by doing a distance__lte querying a table of images called ImagesInstagram.  The form displays all of the images within the set distance as well as a radio button next to each image.  When i select an image's radio button i would like to grab the id of that image and post the id into a new/separate table called ImagesTravel.
     The query to generate the images in the form is working correctly and when i select a radio button and click submit the form, the variable is also populating with the correct id of the image.  However I still am receiving the error as if i'm passing a geo_point incorrectly.  Below is all of the code for this.

## Views

## View to populate the form

```
def curate_detailed_main(request, geo_point):       
   placestring = str(geo_point)
   pnt = GEOSGeometry(placestring)    
   places = ImagesInstagram.objects.filter(geo_point__distance_lte=(pnt, D(km=5)))    
   args = {}
   args.update(csrf(request))
   args['places'] = places
   return render_to_response('curate_detailed_main.html', args)
```

## View that the form submit posts to

```
def curate_detailed_main_auth(request):    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        p = get_object_or_404(ImagesInstagram, pk=instagram_id_num)
        selected_image = p.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
        ImagesTravel.Image_id = selected_image.Image_id
        ImagesTravel.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        return render_to_response('curate_detailed_main.html')
```

## the template

```
<form action="/curate/get/main/auth/" method="post" id="UpdateMain" name="myForm">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" value="Update" />

    {% for place in places %}

<table border="0">
    <tr>            
    <th><img name="low_res_url" src="{{ place.low_res_url}}" width="200"/></th>
            <th><input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}"               value="{{ place.geo_point }}"></th>
    </tr>
</table>

{% endfor %}
</form>
```

I know there are probably several things that need to be corrected in my code, like validating the data in the form, etc... But the code block curate_detailed_main_auth isn't even running because the error is occurring before it even attempts to execute that code block.  I'm very new to django, I've been reading as much as possible and this post is a last resort, because I haven't been able to figure this out myself.  Thanks, I can post any other relevant info that you might need as well, just let me know.

thanks.